# Using cookies, change "unviewed" to "viewed" in db when user views page

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm trying to make a notifications system from scratch after looking around at ready mades and possible integratable versions that fell short.

I'm focusing on one aspect first: notifications for comments.

My database table `comments` looks like this: !(http://oi43.tinypic.com/2zgtaoz.jpg)

When a user submits a comment the recepient's ID is added to the field `to_id`.

`unviewed` is the default status of every comment.

Then I made this code to check for all unviewed comments:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE to_id='$myid' AND status='unviewed'
```

I made some dummy comments and the count works 100%.

I also made a dropdown box to view the notifications in but the code is really long and not crucial to what I need to do next so I'll omit it unless needed to clarify later.

Now I'm trying to find out how I can change the value in the `status` field to 'viewed' when a user clicks through to it from their notifications menu.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this using php and cookies? Just looking for a point in the right direction, my mind is a bit frazzled after writing code all day.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know how I can achieve this using php and cookies? Just looking for a point in the right direction, my mind is a bit frazzled after writing code all day.

You shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Just use one of the analytics frameworks available, such as [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). Note this is usually a paid service.

The approach you propose is slow, not scalable and rather limited.

The way it works, you just add a reference to JavaScript code. This code is located on a content delivery network, which means it is fast to get to the user. Usually, it is much faster than your production server. The code tracks a lot of user activities that can be valuable to a business. In most cases, such analytics is backed by nosql database.

Disclamer: I am *not* connected to any analytics framework in any way.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a notification, I assume it is something basic like a checkbox or similar.

Just do a AJAX request or a simple POST request to a page called, maybe `notif_read.php`

There, get the value of the checkbox clicked and do a database query as follows:

`"UPDATE Comments SET Status='viewed' WHERE to_id = '$myid' AND status='unviewed'"`

Also, try using a simple boolean datatype for the status, since it makes things easier to update and check. Just a thought, will work as it is now.